# How can I ssh to GitHub through a proxy on RedHat?

Tags: github, ssh, proxy, redhat

I am a networking novice trying to ssh from a RedHat 7 server through a proxy to GitHub and not getting anywhere.
The proxy allows ssh traffic through port 2288 to GitHub
The proxy server connection is  : server.proxy.place.organisation.local:8080

I have tried commands such as:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="connect-proxy -S server.proxy.place.organisation.local:8080 %h %p" MyName@github.com
```

but no luck. I don't really understand how I divert ssh on port 22 through to port 2288 on the proxy - do I need to open port 2288 on the RHEL7 server to allow this to pass through? Or is there some part of the ssh command (or config) that takes care of that?